# Why do some elements in list of lists get converted into float datatype, but some do not?

Tags: python, list, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

This is the code where I am reading a csv file to convert into a list of lists so that I can then convert the list of lists into numpy array. These are the columns in the csv file:
`pickup_year`: The year of the trip.
`pickup_month`: The month of the trip (January is 1, December is 12).
`pickup_day`: The day of the month of the trip.
`pickup_location_code`: The airport or borough where the trip started.
`dropoff_location_code`: The airport or borough where the trip finished.
`trip_distance`: The distance of the trip in miles.
`trip_length`: The length of the trip in seconds.
`fare_amount`: The base fare of the trip, in dollars.
`total_amount`: The total amount charged to the passenger, including all fees, tolls and tips.

I am first converting the elements in each list in the list of lists to `float` datatype and then converting the list of lists into `ndarray` as follows:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

# import nyc_taxi.csv as a list of lists
f = open("nyc_taxis.csv", "r")
taxi_list = list(csv.reader(f)) #taxi_list is the list of lists

# remove the header row
taxi_list = taxi_list[1:]

# convert all values to floats
converted_taxi_list = []
for row in taxi_list:
    converted_row = []
    for item in row:
        converted_row.append(float(item))
    converted_taxi_list.append(converted_row)

# start writing your code below this comment
taxi=np.array(converted_taxi_list)
print(taxi.dtype)
print(taxi[:5])
```

The `dtype` of the numpy array is coming out to be `float64`. But when I am printing the first 5 rows of the numpy array, some columns such as `pickup_year`, `pickup_month`, `pickup_day` etc do not show up as floats in the output:

```
[[  2016      1      1      5      0      2      4     21   2037     52
     0.8   5.54  11.65  69.99      1]
 [  2016      1      1      5      0      2      1  16.29   1520     45
     1.3      0      8   54.3      1]
 [  2016      1      1      5      0      2      6   12.7   1462   36.5
     1.3      0      0   37.8      2]
 [  2016      1      1      5      0      2      6    8.7   1210     26
     1.3      0   5.46  32.76      1]
 [  2016      1      1      5      0      2      6   5.56    759   17.5
     1.3      0      0   18.8      2]]
```

Although I'd rather like columns like `pickup_year` to not be floats, but the code should have converted them into floats too. Then why it doesn't?

Comment: Instead of `float` during the list appends, try doing it when creating the array: `np.array(converted_taxi_list, dtype=float)`